# Create CPT on Ajax Call

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I'm creating plugin where I'm providing facility to user that he can create the CPT by putting the name by himself. Ajax call is working fine but CPT is not creating. Any suggestions?

My code is here:

```php
function create_smart_cpt_handler()
{
    $cpt_name = $_POST['cpt_name'];

    // Set the labels. This variable is used in the $args array
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => __($cpt_name),
        'singular_name'      => __('Custom Article'),
        'add_new'            => __('Add New Custom Article'),
        'add_new_item'       => __('Add New Custom Article'),
        'edit_item'          => __('Edit Custom Article'),
        'new_item'           => __('New Custom Article'),
        'all_items'          => __('All Custom Articles'),
        'view_item'          => __('View Custom Article'),
        'search_items'       => __('Search Custom Article'),
    );
    // The arguments for our post type, to be entered as parameter 2 of register_post_type()
    $args = array(
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'description'       => 'Holds our custom article post specific data',
        'public'            => true,
        'menu_position'     => 5,
        'supports'          => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields'),
        'has_archive'       => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
    );
    // Call the actual WordPress function
    // Parameter 1 is a name for the post type
    // Parameter 2 is the $args array
    register_post_type('article', $args);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_create_smart_cpt', 'create_smart_cpt_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_create_smart_cpt', 'create_smart_cpt_handler');
```

Comment: registering a CPT happens on every request, it isn't something you do once that's saved in the database so this doesn't make sense, you can create posts, but you can't register a CPT in an AJAX call like that and expect it to exist outside of that AJAX call. You need to store that information somewhere then call `register_post_type` on every request in the `init` hook. It's the same for custom taxonomies.

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell for this help.